# How to check if the Windows updates are finished on EC2?

Tags: python, powershell, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-ssm

I am looking for a way to determine that a Windows update is complete on on an AWS EC2 instance.

I have a python sktipt with boto3 that is supposed to update a Windows instance and then run some tests. However, the tests fail because the Windows updates are not finished yet.

For the updates I use **ssm.send_command** with the document name [AWS-InstallWindowsUpdates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/patch-manager-ssm-documents.html#patch-manager-ssm-documents-recommended-AWS-InstallWindowsUpdates).

```
import boto3

ssm = boto3.client('ssm', region_name='eu-central-1')
ssm.send_command(InstanceIds=['i-XXXX'], DocumentName='AWS-InstallWindowsUpdates')
```

Now how can I make sure that all updates are installed and I can start testing?

I tried with Get-WUInstallerStatus command from PowerShell in a loop until the output **IsBusy = False** comes.

```
Get-WUInstallerStatus | Select-Object IsBusy | Format-List
```

The command does return IsBusy = False. However, a restart still occur in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

`send_command` is a process that can be monitored through AWS API - [get_command_invocation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.get_command_invocation) so you can check the status of the execution.

After the update process, you can execute `AWS-InstallWindowsUpdates` again with `action` parameter set to `Scan` to ensure that the update ends successfully.

In the case that a process on your Ec2 instance needs to know, if an SSM command is currently running, for Linux instances I check running processes (`ps -aux`).